# Getting birthday from calendar class java

Tags: java, class, oop

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Person {

    private Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
    private String name;
    private int phoneNum;


    public Person (String name, int birthYear, int birthMonth, int birthDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dob.set(birthYear, birthMonth, birthDate);
    }

    public Calendar getDob() {
        return dob;
    }
    public void setDob(Calendar dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getPhoneNum() {
        return phoneNum;
    }
    public void setPhoneNum(int phoneNum) {
        this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
    }

    // I want this to return true if today is my birthday
    public boolean isCurrentDayInMonthSameAsBirthDayInMonth() {
        if (Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH == this.dob.get(this.dob.DAY_OF_MONTH)) {
            return true;
        }
        else { 
            return false;
        }
    }

    // I want this to return true if the month is the same as my birth month
    public boolean isCurrentMonthSameAsBirthMonth() {
        if (Calendar.MONTH == this.dob.get(this.dob.MONTH)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Sorry for the format but everything that I need help with is formatted correctly. I need help setting the dob to whatever date I desire and then testing to see if it is my birthday or if the month is the same as my birth month. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot more strongly advise against using the legacy `java.util.Calendar` and `java.util.Date` classes.  You should use the classes in the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: Note, you can rewrite your boolean methods as following `return Calendar.MONTH == this.dob.get(this.dob.MONTH;` (if else is redundant, in such methods).

Comment: I would use java.time if I could but I have to use java.util.Calendar for this particular assignment

Comment: Maybe you should point your teacher to these comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. `Calendar.MONTH` starts with 0 for January, whereas `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` starts with 1. So you need `this.dob.set(birthYear, birthMonth-1, birthDate);`
2. `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` and `Calendar.MONTH` are field indices and not the day and month of today. You need to create a "today" instance of Calendar and test against that `Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`

As @matoni also suggested, you could shorten your check methods.
@Andreas found a better name for the testing method::

```
// I want this to return true if today is my birthday
public boolean isCurrentDayInMonthSameAsBirthDayInMonth() {
    return isSameAsToday(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}

// I want this to return true if the month is the same as my birth month
public boolean isCurrentMonthSameAsBirthMonth() {
    return isSameAsToday(Calendar.MONTH);
}

private boolean isSameAsToday(int field){
    return Calendar.getInstance().get(field) == this.dob.get(field);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps `isSameAsToday` would be a better name. `isToday` is confusing.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Is today his/her birthday?

```
Boolean isBirthdayToday =
    MonthDay.from( LocalDate.of( 1953 , 1 , 23 ) )
            .equals( 
                MonthDay.from( LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ) 
            ) ;
```

Is this month the month of his/her birthday?

```
Boolean isBirthdayThisMonth =
    Month.from( LocalDate.of( 1953 , 1 , 23 ) )
         .equals( 
             Month.from( LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ) 
         ) ;
```

## Using java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

Your `Person` class’ date-of-birth member variable should be of type `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.of( 1953 , 1 , 23 );
```

I suggest passing `LocalDate` objects around your code rather than mere integers for year-month-day. Doing so makes your code more self-documenting, provides type-safety, and ensures valid values.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

### `MonthDay`

To see if today is the person’s birthday we need to compare month and day while ignoring year. For that, use the [`MonthDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/MonthDay.html) class.

```
MonthDay birthMonthDay = MonthDay.from( birthDate );
MonthDay todayMonthDay= MonthDay.from( today );
Boolean isBirthdayToday = birthMonthDay.equals( todayMonthDay );
```

## `Month`

To compare birth-month rather than month-day of birth, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum. Same idea as the code seen above.

```
Month birthMonth = Month.from( birthDate );
Month todayMonth= Month.from( today );
Boolean isBirthdayThisMonth = birthMonth.equals( todayMonth );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).